# How to draw a background in tikz baposter?

Tags: tikz-pgf, baposter

How I can do the following picture in tikz for put in a poster?

[image]

Comment: Can you specify your question?
Do you want to create this banner with tikz?

Comment: Yes, I would do exactly that. Do you know how?

Comment: Welcome! Presumably, it is a background picture from an external image with the text superimposed. Do you have the image you want to use in some suitable format? A minimal example document including the text would be helpful, even if you don't have a clue how to go about including the external image in the background.

Comment: This is the poster I want to do, mainly the header part

http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-3c6XP2T3g3g/Uk6HHt4v6oI/AAAAAAAABhg/o5b8obIAU3o/s1600/poster.jpg

Comment: Take a look at question 4 in FAQ section from [`ba-poster` site](http://www.brian-amberg.de/uni/poster/)